# Caching array of imgs and after using some of them

Tags: jquery, image

Is there any way to cache images on load and use them from cache when they are needed.

I am using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can cache (or pre-load) an image with javascript like this:

```
<script>
  img1= new Image();
  img1.src="yourimagefile.jpg";
</script>
```